# Validating collection before its elements using FluentValidation in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I have a web api method accepting collection of elements:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostData(PaymentCollection payments)
{
}
```

Both having validator:

```
[Validator(typeof(PaymentCollectionValidator))]
public class PaymentCollection : Collection<Payment>
{
}

[Validator(typeof(PaymentValidator))]
public class Payment
{
}
```

I want to check the collection for length and its elements for validity.

But when I make a request, elements are validated first and collection itself is validated second.

How can I change the order? I need this since I want to limit collection length, say to 5000, and don't want to validate all 5001 elements before throwing an error because collection is too large.

Answer (score 0):

FluentValidation does it intentionally (for now).